# Retrieving info from contact form django

Tags: django, contact-form

I keep working with django and I was building a contact form.

I want to retrieve the information in the contact form, which I was able to do so far, but I am facing the problem that the user that fills in the form is also receiving an email with the information and MY email ( which I don't want ).

I am using the function EmailMultiAlternatives in my view, and have configured propertly my settings.py with the email account, and extra data needed for emails.

Can the information from a form be only received by me (administrator)?

Here is my view:

```
form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        to = #my email
        html_content = "received from [%s] ***message*** %s"%(email,message)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Subject', html_content, 'from@server.com', [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
        msg.send()
```

Comment: I'm confused at what your asking. Are you saying it sends 2 emails?

Comment: Yes, but I have just figured out that it was something with my email account. I have been trying to solve it the whole day !! Thank you for your help !